# Autocomplete with ajax in Symfony2

Tags: jquery-ui, symfony, autocomplete

I'm using jQueryUI autocomplete to get a list of cities. I'm using a json array to display cities, but I just can't get the list to appear.

here is my Ajax function :

```
/**
 * @Route("/ajax", name="ajax")
 */
public function ajaxAction(Request $request)
{
    $value = $request->get('term');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $branches = $em->getRepository('AOFVHFlyBundle:City')
                  ->findByName($value);

    // Get branches by user if non-admin

    $json = array();
    foreach ($branches as $branch) {
        $json[] = array(
            'label' => sprintf('%s (%s)', $branch['name'], $branch['departement']),
            'value' => $branch['id']
        );
    }

    $response = new Response();
    // better way to return json - via header?
    $response->setContent(json_encode($json));

    return $response;
}
```

and here is the form input :

```
    ->add('reqdeparture', 'genemu_jqueryautocompleter_entity', array(
        'class' => 'AOFVH\FlyBundle\Entity\City',
        'property' => 'name',
        'route_name' => 'ajax',
        'attr' => array(
            'placeholder'=>'Départ',
            'autocomplete' => 'on')
        ))
```

Whatever I type in the input, nothing appears.
Any idea why ? (at first I thought it was because collection was too big, but I barely have 50 cities)

Comment: You code seems correct which implies that your error/issue lies elsewhere. Please edit your question and include the html code you are displaying the form in.
On a related note, how big would/could this searchable list of cities get? I ask because I realised you are conducting a text search, I would suggest looking into Elastic Search using FOSElasticBundle. See it in use on my site's homepage here [link](https://campus-discounts.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JsonResponse object. The Content-Type header will be 'application/json'. Symfony manage the chars to escape automatically and others conditions to return a JSON normalized correctly.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

/**
 * @Route("/ajax", name="ajax")
 */
public function ajaxAction(Request $request)
{
    $value = $request->get('term');

    $branches = $this->get("doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager")
                     ->getRepository("NamespaceMyBundle:Entity")
                     ->findByName($value);

    $json = array();
    foreach ($branches as $branch) {
        $json[] = array(…);
    }

    return new JsonResponse($json);
}
```